# How to isolate email signature from global css in webmail

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-signature

In our company, we recently started to use a new webmail interface. I created our email signature html code but when I add the email signature, I realized that webmail's global css effects my signature. Because of effecting, my signature looks differently.

The global css code adds borders to the table in my signature.

I tried many things to isolate my signature but I couldn't be successful. I tried the methods below;

```
- I added style='all:unset' and style='all:revert', but these method didn't work.
- I added style='isolation:isolate' , this didn't work either.
```

I am giving you a simple version of my signature, which looks not like the way I want.

```
<table id="main_div" style="isolation: isolate;" class="testa">
<tr style="isolation: isolate;">
    <td style="isolation: isolate;">
        <img src="https://www.borselboru.com/email/logo_black.png" width="130"  style="max-width: 130px;isolation: isolate;">      
    </td>
    <td style="isolation: isolate;">
        <h3 style="isolation: isolate;">
            <span style="isolation: isolate;">ARİF YILMAZ</span>
            <span style="isolation: isolate;">SATIŞ SORUMLUSU</span>
            <span style="isolation: isolate;">BORSEL BORU TİC. LTD. ŞTİ.</span>
        </h3>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So, if a border is the problem, why not just add `style="border:none!important;"` to the table, and maybe to the all the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements (kinda depends on the styling that gives it a border in the first place)

Comment: You are being very vague. Can you not give us the webmail so we can look at the CSS? Can you not 'inspect' the border and see what style it is, so that we know where it's coming from? Can you you give a screenshot of it's output?